# Creating Matrices

Tags: python, loops, matrix, command

I'm trying to create a game of Minesweeper on python3 and the first thing im trying to do is have the user use command line input for the number of rows and columns that they wish to play with. Then I want to create a matrix based on those two numbers, but with the code below it keeps printing those two numbers that the user inputs instead of creating the actual matrix

```
import sys

def mineBoards(m):
    Rows = len(m)
    Cols = len(m[0])

    for r in range(0,Rows,1):
        for c in range(0,Cols,1):
            print (m[r] [c],end="")
        print()

    return

def main():
    Rows = input(int(sys.argv[1]))
    Cols = input(int(sys.argv[2]))

main()
```

Comment: How are you calling `mineBoards`? how is `m` constructed?

Comment: Also, prefer `raw_input`, and by default, step range is 1, you can omit it.

Comment: @fredtantini I think he is using python 3, that’s why he is using input.

Comment: Or else he wouldn’t add a `int()` in front.

Comment: @thecoder16 you are right, the `print(...)` is only python3

Comment: I need it to be done through command line prompt I know how to do it the other way, the example below is user input, thats why i used the (sys.argv) input

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do:

```
def make_board(rows, columns):
    board = []
    for i in range(rows):
        board.append([])
        for j in range(columns):
            board[i].append(“-“)
    return board
number_of_rows = int(input(“Number of rows: “))
number_of_cols = int(input(“Number of columns: “))
game_board = make_board(number_of_rows, number_of_cols)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ditch the `global`! Simply create a new list in `make_board` then `return` it. `board = make_board(number_of_rows, number_of_cols)`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
rows = int(input("Number of rows: "))
cols = int(input("Number of columns: "))
board = [['-' for x in range(cols)] for y in range(rows)]
```

After that, the board will be a list of lists with dimensions `rows x cols`.
You can of course substitute the `'-'` with anything else, this is just an example.

Comment: Um… I tested your code and it printed the opposite. If I said 4 rows and 5 columns, the board becomes 5 rows and 4 columns. To change, just flip the “for x…” and "for y…" comprehensions.